# Prepend hex string to the content of binary file

Tags: ruby, string, file, binary, prepend

I have these 2 arrays representing hexadecimal numbers and I want to write to a file in binary format.

I convert to hexadecimal string like this:

```
a=["A2","48","04","03","EE","72","B4","6B"]
b=["1A","28","18","06","07","00","11","86","05","01","01","01","A0"]

hex_string1 = a.map{|b| b.to_i(16)}.pack("C*")
hex_string2 = b.map{|b| b.to_i(16)}.pack("C*")
```

Now I want to write to a file the `hex_string2` first and then prepend (with offset "0") the `hex_string1` to the file.

I'm proceeding like this but the output is incorrect.

```
File.binwrite("outfile.bin",hex_string2)
File.binwrite("outfile.bin",hex_string1,0)
```

The current output is:

```
A2 48 04 03 EE 72 B4 6B 05 01 01 01 A0
```

And the correct content within the "output.bin" would be like this:

```
A2 48 04 03 EE 72 B4 6B 1A 28 18 06 07 00 11 86 05 01 01 01 A0
```

How would be the way to do this?

Comment: Why don't write first string to the file then append second string to it?

Comment: Hi Ivan. That's is a logic question. The issue is in my code I generate an array within a foreach() loop. The array initially is empty but in the loop is filled up doing something like this `array << data` several times until end of the loop. If I set the array = a at the beginning of the `foreach()` the content of array "a" is appended several times to Array. And if I set Array=a before the foreach() loop I get error because the Array doesn't exist or is taken as a different array. I hope make sense. But I think the solution goes doing something like you say.

Comment: To be honest, I did not fully understand your comment, but if it is necessary to keep this order of writing strings, why not to write second string with the offset by the size of first string: File.binwrite("outfile.bin",hex_string2,hex_string1.size); 
    File.binwrite("outfile.bin",hex_string1,0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write second string with the offset by the size of first string:

```
File.binwrite("outfile.bin",hex_string2,hex_string1.size)
File.binwrite("outfile.bin",hex_string1,0)
```

In this case you'll get exactly what you want:

```
A2 48 04 03 EE 72 B4 6B 1A 28 18 06 07 00 11 86 05 01 01 01 A0
```